# Deserialize Nested JSON to Lists

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json-deserialization

I am trying to bind a drop-down with these lists in my View. Not able to convert the below JSON collections to LISTS.

My JSON string is in this format:

```
 ["AppTypes",
 [
    {
        "AppTypeID": "5136",
        "AppType": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "AppTypeID": "dca6",
        "AppType": "MNO"
    },
    {
        "AppTypeID": "d8de",
        "AppType": "PQR"
    }
],
"CompTypes",
[
    {
        "CompTypeID": "0425",
        "CompType": "STU"
    },        
    {
        "CompTypeID": "0426",
        "CompType": "EDC"
    },
    {
        "CompTypeID": "0444",
        "CompType": "PLM"
    }
]
]
```

I am trying to deserialize the code, but not getting through. My Class,

```
     public class DAL
     {
           public DAL() { }
           public CompList CompList { get; set; }
     }

     public class CompList
     {
         public CompList()
         {
              AppTypes = new List<AppTypes>();
              CompType = new List<CompTypes>();                   
         }
         public List<AppTypes> AppTypes;
         public List<ComTypes> CompType;
     }
     public class AppTypes
     {
         public Guid AppTypeID { get; set; }
         public string AppType { get; set; }
     }

     public class CompTypes
     {
         public Guid CompTypeID { get; set; }
         public string CompType { get; set; }
     }

     public class JSONSerializer
     {
          public static T ConvertFromJSON<T>(String json)
          {
              JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
              return serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
          }
     }
```

Controller Code:

```
    dynamic obj = JSONSerializer.ConvertFromJSON<DAL>(JsonData);
```

Not able to get where I am going wrong. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your JSON is really weird. In fact, it's not even valid. You will not be able to deserialize invalid JSON with a `Deserialize` call. You will need to use a JsonReader or something.

Comment: Also, I would recommend to use JSON.NET rather than the `JavaScriptSerializer` since it's WAAAYY more performant and more flexible.

Comment: Your lists for `AppTypes` and `CompType` aren't properties (no getter/settters). If the json was valid, it would be bound correctly by the `DefaultModelBinder` anyway so all this is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for the response, have updated the JSON. Is there anything I can implement now?

Comment: Your json is still not valid - `{AppTypes: [ { "AppTypeID": "5136", "AppType": "ABC" }, {..} ], CompType: [ {..}, {..} ] }`, and you don't have `{ get; set; }` on `AppTypes` and `CompType`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - the JSON is valid, try posting it into http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.  It's just weird, in that it consists of an array of 4 items: 2 strings; and two sub-arrays of objects.  Certainly I would not suggest creating JSON like that (it probably should be as you suggest) but OP may not have control over the JSON he/she must process.

Comment: @dbc, You may strictly be right, but I don't think its valid in relation to the `Type` OP is trying to serialize to (which in any case would be `CompList`, not `DAL` based on the property names).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that your JSON represents a top-level array containing either strings or nested arrays containing objects, but you are trying to deserialize this into a top-level object - not an array.  Your class design is quite reasonable, but a serializer such as [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) isn't really designed to completely restructure a data model in this way during deserialization.  You may need to deserialize into a more literal representation of the JSON, then restructure the data with, say, Linq.

A secondary problem is that you are declaring your `ID` properties to be Guids, but the corresponding JSON properties (such as `"AppTypeID": "5136"`) do not have enough digits to be Guids.  `JavaScriptSerializer` expects a Guid to [have 32 digits, optionally separated by hyphens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g.: `"d70d7583-b2e6-4f6e-8d99-2022d3ca2b10"` or `"d70d7583b2e64f6e8d992022d3ca2b10"`.

Thus, if I change your Guid properties to strings:

```
public class AppTypes
{
    public string AppTypeID { get; set; }
    public string AppType { get; set; }
}

public class CompTypes
{
    public string CompTypeID { get; set; }
    public string CompType { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can deserialize and convert to a `CompList` as follows:

```
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var array = js.Deserialize<List<object>>(JsonData); // Deserialize outer array
        var compList = new CompList
        {
            AppTypes = array
                .OfType<IEnumerable<object>>()          // Enumerate through nested arrays
                .SelectMany(o => o)                     // Enumerate through elements in nested arrays
                .OfType<IDictionary<string, object>>()  // Pick out those which are JSON objects (deserialized as dictionaries)
                .Where(d => d.ContainsKey("AppType"))   // Filter those that are AppTypes 
                .Select(d => js.ConvertToType<AppTypes>(d)) // Deserialize to the AppTypes class
                .ToList(),
            CompType = array
                .OfType<IEnumerable<object>>()
                .SelectMany(o => o)
                .OfType<IDictionary<string, object>>()
                .Where(d => d.ContainsKey("CompType"))
                .Select(d => js.ConvertToType<CompTypes>(d))
                .ToList(),
        };
```

FYI, your original code could deserialize JSON that looks like this into a `CompList`:

```
{
  "AppTypes": [
    {
      "AppTypeID": "5136",
      "AppType": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "AppTypeID": "dca6",
      "AppType": "MNO"
    },
    {
      "AppTypeID": "d8de",
      "AppType": "PQR"
    }
  ],
  "CompType": [
    {
      "CompTypeID": "0425",
      "CompType": "STU"
    },
    {
      "CompTypeID": "0426",
      "CompType": "EDC"
    },
    {
      "CompTypeID": "0444",
      "CompType": "PLM"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the outermost JSON is an object with two array-valued properties rather than an array of two strings and two arrays.